# Reshaping 2D to 3D produce not expected output

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

The objective is to reshape a 2D array

```
[[1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [1 2 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 2]
 [1 2 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [1 2 1 1]
 [1 2 1 1]
 [1 2 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2]
 [1 2 1 1]]
```

into 3D array

```
   [[[1 1]
  [1 1]
  [1 1]
  [1 1]
  [2 1]
  [2 2]
  [2 1]]

 [[1 2]
  [1 1]
  [1 2]
  [2 2]
  [2 2]
  [2 2]
  [2 2]]

 [[1 1]
  [1 1]
  [1 1]
  [1 1]
  [2 1]
  [2 2]
  [2 1]]

 [[1 1]
  [1 1]
  [1 1]
  [1 1]
  [2 1]
  [2 2]
  [2 1]]]
```

Currently, the code below produced the intended output

```
import numpy as np

arr=np.array([[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1],
  [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2],
  [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1],[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1]]).transpose()


nnodes_size=7
nsize=arr.shape[0]
nrow=int(nsize/nnodes_size)

arrls=[np.reshape(arr[:,idx],(nrow,-1)).transpose() for idx in range(arr.shape[1])]
arr_opt=np.array(arrls)
```

I wish to simplified the reshaping process into the following

```
np.reshape(arr, (-1, nsize, nrow))
```

However, this does not produced the intended output.

May I know what intermediate process that I might have miss?

Comment: Can you print the outputs with commas?

Comment: Hi @MadPhysicist, I am not clear about your comment nor the issue about mismatch array? My compiler (Pycharm) return the output as it is, I am not so sure how to produce the comma as request

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully understand how you were making the array. My fault. Comments retracted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide `nsize` by 2 to get `7` instead of `14`:

```
>>> np.reshape(arr, (-1, nsize // 2, nrow))
array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2]],

       [[2, 2],
        [2, 2],
        [2, 2],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[2, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 1]]])
```

Comment: argh, should have notice that.thanks

Comment: Do it solve your problem? :)

Comment: I am afraid your suggestion cannot be generalise for `arr=np.array([[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1],
  [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2],
  [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1],[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1]]).transpose()`

Comment: What's wrong with my code on that? It doesn't throw an error for me, it gives me this array: `np.array([[[1,1],[1,1],[1,1],[1,1],[1,1],[1,1],[1,2]],[[1,1],[2,2],[2,2],[2,2],[2,2],[2,2],[2,2]],[[1,2],[1,1],[1,1],[1,1],[1,2],[1,1],[1,2]],[[1,1],[1,2],[1,1],[2,2],[2,2],[1,2],[1,1]]])`. What do you expect instead?

Comment: Hi @richardec. Really appreciate for the time entertaining this issue. I have update the thread to reflect for my comment above